# Could Not Serialize object to .\Sample.xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to serialize an object to xml, and I have the error below:

```
: Could Not Serialize object to .\Sample.xml
```

The inner exception is:

```
There was an error reflecting type 'SiteProvisioningFramework.Entities.SiteDefinition'.
```

The serializing code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var siteDefinition = new SiteDefinition();
            siteDefinition.Name = "ContosoIntranet";
            siteDefinition.Version = "1.0.0.0";
            siteDefinition.MasterPages = new List<SiteProvisioningFramework.MasterPage>()
            {
                new MasterPage(){
                    Name="seattle.master",
                    ServerFolder ="_catalogs/ContosoIntranet/",
                    UIVersion = "15",
                    Url="",
                    LocalFolder = ".MasterPages/seattle.master"
                }
            };


            Utilities.XmlHelper.ObjectToXml(siteDefinition, @".\Sample.xml");
        }

 public static void ObjectToXml(object obj, string path_to_xml)
        {
            //serialize and persist it to it's file
            try
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
                FileStream fs = File.Open(
                    path_to_xml,
                    FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                    FileAccess.Write,
                    FileShare.ReadWrite);
                ser.Serialize(fs, obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Could Not Serialize object to " + path_to_xml,
                    ex);
            }
        }
```

The classes are:

```
 public class SiteDefinition
        {
            [XmlAttribute ()]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute()]
            public string Version { get; set; }
            public List<MasterPage> MasterPages { get; set; }
            public List<File> Files { get; set; }
            public List<PageLayout> PageLayouts { get; set; }
            public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
            public List<ContentType> ContentTypes { get; set; }
            public List<StyleSheet> StyleSheets { get; set; }
        }

     public class MasterPage : File
        {
            [XmlAttribute()]
            public string UIVersion { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute()]
            public string MasterPageDescription { get; set; }    
        }

    public class File
        {
            [XmlAttribute()]
            public string Url { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute()]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute()]
            public string LocalFolder { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute()]
            public string ServerFolder { get; set; }
        }

 public class Field
    {
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }

    }

  public class Feature
    {
        public string Guid { get; set; }

    }

   public class ContentType
    {
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    }

  public class List
    {
        public List<ContentType> ContentTypes { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


    }

 public class PageLayout : File
    {

        public string UIVersion { get; set; }
        public string MasterPageDescription { get; set; }    
    }

 public class StyleSheet : File
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

 public class Theme
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ColorFilePath { get; set; }
        public string FontFilePath { get; set; }
        public string BackgroundImagePath { get; set; }
        public MasterPage MasterPage { get; set; }

    }
```

any idea?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in the classes you've shown, but what are the other classes (PageLayout, Feature, ContentType, StyleSheet)? And is there any more detail in the exception ? An inner inner exception perhaps?

Comment: Also, your serialization code never closes the file... but that's probably unrelated to your problem.

Comment: You should get into the habit of displaying the entire exception. Catch the exception, then display `ex.ToString()`. You'll find out exactly what the problem is. You also need to put that `FileStream` into a `using` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error lies with one property in your `SiteDefinition` class -

`public List<ContentType> ContentTypes { get; set; }`

A `System.Net.Mime.ContentType` apparently can't be serialized. If you put an `XmlIgnore` attribute on it, the code runs fine.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public List<ContentType> ContentTypes { get; set; }
```

### Edit:

Your `ContentType` is a custom class - so that is not it. But your `Name` property in your `StyleSheet` class is hiding the exact same property in the class that it inherits from (`File`) - this is causing the serialization error.

Comment: Assuming that ContentType in the OP's code is indeed `System.Net.Mime.ContentType`... It might be a custom class.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque True, but given his other class names that deal with web stuff I thought it was relatively safe to assume the full namespace of the `ContentType` class.

Comment: I have edited the question with all code from my custom classes

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I stand corrected. Should have played it safe and do what I usually do - **never assume**